# Is the derivative formula itself complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be complex differentiable on an open set $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ (and therefore holomorphic on said set, according to my teacher, since in my class we consider this implies the derivative is continuous), show that :

$g(z)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\displaystyle{\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}} & z\neq z_0\\
f'(z_0) & z=z_0\\
\end{array}
\right.$

is complex diffentiable on $U$. I have already managed to show that the derivative exists if $z\neq z_0$:

$g'(z)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}=\frac{f'(z)-g(z)}{z-z_0}}$

But I get stuck when trying to find the derivative for $z=z_0$ :

$\begin{array}{rcl}
g'(z_0) & = & \displaystyle{\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}}\\
& = & \displaystyle{\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)}{z-z_0}}\\
& = & \displaystyle{\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{(z-z_0)^2}-\frac{f'(z_0)}{z-z_0}}\\
\end{array}$

I felt like I could conclude after the second line because $\displaystyle{\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{(z-z_0)}}=f'(z_0)$ and then I'd have 0, but one of my classmates told me that I couldn't do that, because of continuity issues.
How do I calculate the derivative for $z=z_0$ then ? Should I prove that $g'(z)$ is continuous ?

Comment: I assume Taylor expansion is not available yet?

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer, posting it in case anyone needs it:

$f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+f''(z_0)(z-z_0)/2+o(z^2)$

Therefore :

$g'(z_0)=\displaystyle{\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{(z-z_0)^2}-\frac{f'(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\frac{f''(z_0)}{2}}$

So there you go, I think this is correct.

Comment: Do you have more than one account? If so, you can merge them together. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thank you but I made a mistake when typing my email after asking the question so I can't access the other account.

Comment: If you read the link, you see SE will reach out to you to verify so that may not be an issue.